# Ubuntu 18.04 python3.7 confluent-kafka no module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'

Tags: python, confluent-kafka-python

I have VM run on ubuntu 18.04.
On that I installed:

- python3.7
- confluent-kafka
  when run python script, I met this message error:

```
    from .cimpl import (Consumer, #noqa
    
    ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'confluent_kafka.cimpl'
```

I've tried to run/install/remove in many ways but this error still occurred.

Answer (score 3):

Install modules confluent_kafka

```
pip3 install confluent_kafka
```

or try these steps

```
sudo apt-get install librdkafka1 librdkafka-dev libssl-dev liblz4-dev libsasl2-dev
git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python.git
cd confluent-kafka-python; ./configure ; make ; sudo make install
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python